# How to find out which radio button was chosen by the user?

Tags: c++, qt, radio-button, qt5

I have four radio buttons, the user must choose one of the four radio buttons.

[image]

The problem is each radio button has its own name that differs from the others.

**How to find out which radio button was chosen by the user ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the buttons into a `GroupBox` and use `findChildren`, after this you can use `QButtonGroup` or simply iterate through all Buttons list and check name of `radiobutton`. It is efficient way because it works with 4 button or 1000, you should write big code if you have many buttons.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_15_clicked(){
    QButtonGroup group;
    QList<QRadioButton *> allButtons = ui->groupBox->findChildren<QRadioButton *>();
    qDebug() <<allButtons.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); ++i)
    {
        group.addButton(allButtons[i],i);
    }
    qDebug() << group.checkedId();
    qDebug() << group.checkedButton();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a simple inquiry related to the same question: is it possible to set value to each radio button like `setData()`.

Comment: @LionKing yes, documentation said that you can setIcon and setText to the button.

Comment: No problem, about my inquiry, I mean I want to set hidden value or data to each radio button like `setData()` function  to get it later. is it possible to do that.

Comment: @LionKing Oh,I understood. No, buttons have not display or another roles, but every button is a QObject subclass so you can set custom property, using setProperty method and read it by property method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '[isChecked()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop)' command that all qt buttons support, and check each radio button. Or, you can connect a function to the 'toggled(bool isChecked)' signal, and use that to update a value indicating which of the four radio buttons is checked.

Comment: What about the name of each radio button, no problem if each radio button has its own name differs from the other.

Comment: You should definitely name your radio buttons after what their labels say, and keep track of them in the code. You _can_ use the [text()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop) command, but you have to select which radio button you use it from anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric values of the four IDs should be continuous. Given that, call GetCheckedRadioButton to determine which one is selected.

Comment: is `GetCheckedRadioButton` function in Qt5 ?